# Adding padding to a specific div makes my page menu double

Tags: html, css

When adding padding, margin, just general distance to a text element on my page, my top menu kind of "mirrors" down on the page and i get a non-functional second menu at the middle of the page. Identical to the second one, and cuts through all other elements like images, text, etc.. Colors and all other aspects are still retained on the new menu and on the page in general.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>something</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body class="fade-in">

<div id="meny">
    <div id="menyknapp1">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Mobile Enheter</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="">Enheter</a>
        <a href="">Operativsystemer</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="menyknapp2">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Teknologi</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="">Webtjenester</a>
        <a href="">Teknologier</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="bilde1">
    <img src="Technology.png" style="width: 400px; height: 350px;">
</div>
</div> </div>
<div id="tekst">
    <p> text
</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
@import url('https://rsms.me/inter/inter-ui.css');

/*fade in animasjon body */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.fade-in {
  opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
  -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
  -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
  animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;

  -webkit-animation-duration:0.3s;
  -moz-animation-duration:0.3s;
  animation-duration:0.3s;
}


body {

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 2%;

}

#meny {

    background-color: #CACACA;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;

}


#tekst 
{
    top: 20%;
    font-family: 'Inter UI', 'sans-serif';
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #89cff0;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Inter UI', 'sans-serif';
    border-radius: 3px;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #89cff0;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Inter UI', 'sans-serif';
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #6599b2;
}

#menyknapp1 {

    position: absolute;
    left: 3%;
    top: 10%;
    padding: auto;

}

#menyknapp2 {

position: absolute;
left: 20%;
padding: auto;
top: 10%;
}

#tekst {

    margin-left: 18px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 

}

#bilde1 {

    position: absolute;
    left: 18px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with absolute position in your .dropdown-content css definition.

Maybe take some time to understand how absolute positioning works: 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: What positioning do you suggest i use on the element? I tried a few on the webpage you linked but all of them just seemed to stick my element in place where i couldn't move it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Set relative position on the #menyknapp1 & 2 elements then set absolute positioning on the dropdown elements. This would allow the dropdowns to be absolute positioned relative to the menu item.